# mysql join two rows with same column value and calculate certain column values and return all rows in one row

Tags: mysql

I have a table name `agents_commission` have columns id, agent_id, deal_id, commission, deal_date.

[image: agents_commission]

I want to select `agent_id`, `commission` from `agents_commission` where month(`date_deal`) = '$month' and year(`date_deal`) ='$year';

but if the table have some rows have the same `agent_id` join the same rows in one row and calculate the `commission` values like row 66666.7 + 100000 as in row 1, 2

to be the final fetch_assoc as

array('agent_id'=>1, 'commision'=>166666.7);

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not select all when you want to group by only one column(agentid). you can do something like below

```
select agent_id, sum(commission) as commission from temp where MONTH(deal_date) = '09' and year(deal_date) ='2018' group by agent_id;
```

***The SELECT statement used in the GROUP BY clause can only be used contain column names, aggregate functions, constants and expressions.***

Refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: Thanks very mauch ^^

Answer (score 2):

Try using group by and aggregation:

```
select agentid, sum(commission) as commission
from agents_commission
where month(date_deal) = '$month' and year(date_deal) ='$year';
group by agentid
```